# Join razor output with separator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My ASP.NET MVC5 site view contains this logic:

```
<td nowrap>
    @if (item.CanUnblock)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Unblock", "Unblock", new { @id = item.Id })
    }
    @if (item.CanSuspend)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Suspend", "Suspend", new { @id = item.Id })
    }
</td>
```

This means if we can `unblock` and `suspend` we can see both links:

```
Unblock Suspend
```

which are next to each other. What I want to do is to add a separator.

I can do something like this:

```
<td nowrap>
    @if (item.CanUnblock)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Unblock", "Unblock", new { @id = item.Id }) @:|
    }
    @if (item.CanSuspend)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Suspend", "Suspend", new { @id = item.Id })
    }
</td>
```

And it would produce:

```
Unblock | Suspend
```

which is what I expected. The problem is that if I can only `Unblock` I would see:

```
Unblock |
```

but if only 1 link is visible, I expected something like this:

```
Unblock
```

How can I do it without ugly solutions like storing information about separator in variable, like `isSeparatorAdded`?

Comment: You could introduce another `if` condition betwen your two current `if's` and do something like `if(item.CanUnblock && item.Suspend) { <span>|</span> }`

Comment: @Izzy In fact there are more that 2 ifs. What if first and third `if` would return `true`? A lot of messy code.

Comment: you could create list Tuple<boolean, string> where boolean is flag whether item should be shown and string is corresponding url. then you should just iterate your list through foreach, and if item is not last - insert delimiter.